# How to use jquery .not or .filter with data-attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, filter, selector

Javascript woes today... I'm struggleing to get a selector right.

I need to select elements, that don't have `jqmData(bound) === true` in a jQuery chained statement. This is what I have:

```
var swipesOnPage = $('div.photoswipeable');
...
swipesOnPage.not(':jqmData(bound="true")')
            .jqmData('bound', true )
            .each( function(){
                // do stuff
            });
```

I need to flag lables that received their "treatment" so I'm not re-running code on them. However I cannot get the selector right, so all elements, which I have set `jqmData("bound",true)` get re-selected every time.

**Question:**
How to use the `not` or `filter` statement correctly with data-attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $someCollection = $('div.photoswipeable').filter(function() {
    return $(this).jqmData("bound") !== true;
});
```

Comment: perfect. changed "bould" to "bound".